# How to populate the sitemap?

Tags: 7

I would like to generate a sitemap using the Site Map module.

I've enabled some menus to show up. But how do I change the order of the information displayed? Also, I don't want Menu titles to be displayed in the sitemap.
How would I go about populating the sitemap?

Comment: What do you mean by "proper way"?  Is this a site map for users or for search engines?  If it's for search engines, I don't think you really need to worry about the order, just the priority.

Comment: Google has guidelines for sitemaps here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668#1

Comment: Sorry, I should rephrase that. What I meant to ask was "How do I populate the sitemap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [XML Sitemap](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module, the most popular sitemap module on Drupal.org, you don't actually need to populate the sitemap yourself.  Instead, you simply configure what you want to appear on the sitemap, and then the sitemap is automatically generated when cron runs.

Here's how to set up a sitemap on Drupal 7.

1. Install and enable XML sitemap.
2. Go to /admin/config/search/xmlsitemap and add a sitemap (you only need to add one if your site only has one language; if you have multiple languages, you can add a sitemap for each language).
3. Navigate to the items you want to add to the sitemap.  If your items are all contained on menus, the easiest way to do this is to go to the "edit menu" page for each menu, scroll down to the XML sitemap options, and make sure the menu is set to be included.
4. Wait for cron to run or manually run cron yourself.  You can then go back to the XML sitemap configuration page  (/admin/config/search/xmlsitemap) to confirm that the content was added properly.

If you need custom links, just click the "custom links" tab.  Also, the "search engines" tab allows you to automatically submit the sitemap to Google and Bing, which is a pretty useful feature.

Comment: The question is about the [Site map](http://drupal.org/project/site_map) module.

Comment: I wondered that but I wasn't sure; in any case, this describes how to use XML Sitemap as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you Patrick.
Any ideas on how to get the Site map module to work instead?

Comment: @kine456 No, sorry, I only have experience with XML Sitemap.